# Stagger/Split insert loop for fork()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fork

I have a page that collects different data, in this case names, height, weight, etc. I use a loop to go over the rows and then I am inserting them into my SQL database one line at a time. Each page has 1,000 rows and that takes a while to insert each row per page. I'm interested in trying to use workers to split the task more efficiently but I'm not sure I understand clusters and forks fully. Is there a way I can give 4 workers something like 250 inserts each? With my current setup the workers obvious just all do the same lines and that leads to 4,000 inserts rather than the 1,000 unique ones.

**Inside My Loop**

```
//Insert And Log
var sql = "INSERT INTO split.test (person_id,name,height,weight) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
con.query(sql, [input_id,input_name,input_height_input_weight], function (err, rows, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log(input_id+" inserted");
    });

>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180
>> 2 John Smith 66 140
>> etc
```

**What I Currently Get**

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var p = 0; p < numCPUs; p++) {
    cluster.fork();

    //Insert And Log
    var sql = "INSERT INTO split.test (person_id,name,height,weight) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    con.query(sql, [input_id,input_name,input_height_input_weight], function (err, rows, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
          console.log(input_id+" inserted");
      });
}
} else {
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end('process ' + process.pid + ' says hello!');
  }).listen(8000);
}

>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180 [Worker 1]
>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180 [Worker 2]
>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180 [Worker 3]
>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180 [Worker 4]
>> 2 John Smith 66 140 [Worker 1]
>> 2 John Smith 66 140 [Worker 2]
>> 2 John Smith 66 140 [Worker 3]
>> 2 John Smith 66 140 [Worker 4]
>> etc
```

**What I Want**

```
>> 1 Howard Jones 72 180 [Worker 1]
>> 2 John Smith 66 140 [Worker 2]
>> 3 Chris Christopher 69 220 [Worker 3]
>> 4 Matt Matthew 68 150 [Worker 4]
>> etc
```

Comment: Instead of introducing all the complexity with forking, why not just juggle multiple in-progress queries using multiple database connections and promises?

Comment: @tadman so when I run this with a limit of 500 per page, it speeds along decently. If I load 1000 in a page however, it slows the process down. I was hoping to be able to have one process run the pages with the names and then have the forked processes do the inserting.

Comment: That's just how non-blocking code needs to work. Keep your chunks small and more frequent.